# Observing contents of a specific DIV

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there a way to observe the contents of a specific DIV, I want to call a function as soon as the contents of the DIV are changed.

This can be a innerHTML replace, a page load.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the contents of the element comparing to the previous value.

Retrieve the element to watch

```
var div = document.getElementById("w");
```

Create a watcher:

```
var w1 = { watch: null, prev: div.innerHTML };
```

Start the watcher. Each 100ms it will compare the previous value to the current value, if it's different it will update the value and trigger any actions.

```
function Watch(w, e)
{
    w.watch = setInterval(function() {
       if (e.innerHTML != w.prev)
       {
           w.prev = e.innerHTML;
           alert("changed");
       }
    }, 100);
}

Watch(w1, div);
```

**[See this example on jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.net/t8QYJ/)**

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers you can use *DOM mutation events* like `DOMSubtreeModified`, `DOMCharacterDataModified`. In IE you've got `onchange` event which you can use. For all the other browsers you can set up a *timer* for checking if the content has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

In [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), it says that DIVs should fire OnChange when their content is modified.

Observing a div for change is not an effective technique. Have you looked into getting the code that changes the DIV's content to trigger and event?

Alternatively you could set a timer that monitors changes in your div and triggers some event.